# Using LINQ to find duplicates across multiple properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, duplicates

Given a class with the following definition:

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public int ValueA { get; set; }
    public int ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

How can duplicate values be found in a MyTestClass[] array?

For example,

```
MyTestClass[] items = new MyTestClass[3];
items[0] = new MyTestClass { ValueA = 1, ValueB = 1 };
items[1] = new MyTestClass { ValueA = 0, ValueB = 1 };
items[2] = new MyTestClass { ValueA = 1, ValueB = 1 };
```

Contains a duplicate as there are two MyTestClass objects where ValueA **and** ValueB both = 1

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can find your duplicates by grouping your elements by ValueA and ValueB.
Do a count on them afterwards and you will find which ones are duplicates.

This is how you would isolate the dupes :

```
var duplicates = items.GroupBy(i => new {i.ValueA, i.ValueB})
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
  .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! You win an internet. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use Jon Skeet's `DistinctBy` and `Except` together to find duplicates.  See [this Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property?lq=1) for his explanation of `DistinctBy`.

```
MyTestClass[] items = new MyTestClass[3];
items[0] = new MyTestClass { ValueA = 1, ValueB = 1 };
items[1] = new MyTestClass { ValueA = 0, ValueB = 1 };
items[2] = new MyTestClass { ValueA = 1, ValueB = 1 };

MyTestClass [] distinctItems = items.DistinctBy(p => new {p.ValueA, p.ValueB}).ToArray();
MyTestClass [] duplicates = items.Except(distinctItems).ToArray();
```

It will only return one item and not both duplicates however.

Answer (score 1):

MyTestClass should implement the Equals method.

```
public bool Equals(MyTestClass x, MyTestClass y)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) ||
        Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.ValueA == y.ValueA && y.ValueB == y.ValueB;
}
```

Here you have a [good article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types.aspx) about it.

After that you can get a "clean" list of MyTestClass with "Distinct" method.

Comment: If Distinct is gonna work, you'll have to do more than implement the Equals method. You should implement the IEquatable<MyTestClass> interface and make sure that you implement GetHashCode and object equals properly.

Comment: Right, my fault ;-) Anyway it's not too much work... and it can be interesting in many scenarios ;-)