# Get a list of duplicates from list based on properties comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Demo>`

```
public class Demo
{
    public Demo()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The Id property is unique for every record in the list.

How can I get a `List<Demo>` from the original `List<Demo>` with all the duplicates where the Name and Title are same.

What I did so far but what I get is one single record:

```
List<Demo> demo = new List<Demo>();

demo.Add(new Demo()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Demo",
    Title = "A"
});

demo.Add(new Demo()
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Demo",
    Title = "A"
});

demo.Add(new Demo()
{
    Id = 3,
    Name = "Demo",
    Title = "A"
});

demo.Add(new Demo()
{
    Id = 4,
    Name = "Demo1",
    Title = "A"
});

demo.Add(new Demo()
{
    Id = 5,
    Name = "Demo2",
    Title = "A"
});
```

and then i am doing:

```
var duplicates = demo.GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.Title })
                     .Where(t => t.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

From the example above I should get a `List<Demo>` with the first 3 items where the ids are:1,2,3 because Name and Title are same.

Comment: [Using LINQ to find duplicates across multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596604/using-linq-to-find-duplicates-across-multiple-properties)

Comment: @LeiYang: Nope, still one record returned.

Comment: Yes, you'll only get one result - but that's a group with three elements. Bear in mind that you could have multiple groups (e.g. multiple "Demo2/A" records). It's not clear what you expect in that situation.

Comment: @user2818430 what do you mean? if you tried using the link's method then paste your latest code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LINQ to find duplicates across multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596604/using-linq-to-find-duplicates-across-multiple-properties)

Comment: @JonSkeet: The list should include all duplicates. If there are multiple Demo2/A those should be included in the list also

Comment: So you'd want a *single* list that included all Demo/A elements and all Demo2/A elements?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like all you're missing is a `SelectMany` call. Currently you're creating all the appropriate groups and filtering down to groups with more than one entry - but if you want a single flat list, you need to flatten those groups back to their elements:

```
var duplicates = demo
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.Title })
    .Where(t => t.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x) // Flatten groups to a single sequence
    .ToList();
```

Note that this *doesn't* mean every entry in the resulting list will have the same name and title. It does mean that every entry will have a name/title combination in common with at least one other entry.

Comment: can you still advise how to ignore empty strings? if for example I have records where Name and Title are empty strings

Comment: @user2818430: You should ask that as a separate question, after trying it for yourself. (Hint: filter them right at the start with a `Where` clause.)

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there.

`Groupby` divides a sequence into groups. Each group has something in common: the `Key` of the group. Each group is a sequence containing all elements in the original sequence that match the key.

Your key is `new { t.Name, t.Title }`. Your original sequence will be divided into groups of object that had the same name / title:

- **Group Demo / A** contains three elements: Id = 1, Id = 2, Id = 3
- **Group Demo1 / A** contains only element Id = 4
- **Group Demo2 / A** contains only element Id = 5

The `Where` after you group returns a sequence of `IGrouping`. This sequence contains only one element: the only group that has more than one element. This is the group with key Demo/A.

Your specification was not a sequence of IGrouping (where each group is a sequence of `Demo`), but one list of `Demo` that contains all elements with duplicate Name/Title.

This means you have to take the elements from all groups after your `Where` (in your example this sequence contains only one group) and concatenate all these groups into one sequence. This is done by [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
IEnumerable<Demo> duplicates = demo
    .GroupBy(demoElement => new {demoElement.Name, demoElement.Title})
    .Where(group => group.Skip(1).Any())
    .SelectMany(group => group);
```

The `SelectMany` takes the sequence of each group and concatenates all sequences into one sequence.

By the way, did you notice that I didn't use Count() to detect if there are duplicates, but `Skip(1).Any()`. If one of your groups would have hundreds of elements, it would be enough to stop counting after the first element. It is a waste of computing power to count all elements to detect if there is more than one.

One final hint: don't use `ToList()` if you are not certain you need it. If the user of your piece of code only wants the first element, or the first few, it is a waste if you calculate all elements into a list. Keep it `IEnumerable<Demo>` as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hers's what you want if you have more than 1 title and names are same. Say the last object is `Demo1` and `A`.

```
var duplicates = demo.GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.Title }).Where(t => t.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(x => new { Count = x.Count(), Values = x.Select(y => y)})
                     .ToList();
```

What this does it, gives you count and all the grouped values (based on Name and Title) and their Count.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you ,

List duplicates = demo.GroupBy(grp => new { grp.Name, grp.Title }).SelectMany(selm => selm.Skip(1)).Distinct().ToList();

It is working fine as per your expected answer.